# web api response to angular class mapping

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I have web api action method returning chapterid and chaptername. I want to map this to angular class with an extra field of 'Edit' whose default value is false

```
export class Chapter {
  chapterid: number;
  chaptername: string;
  Edit: boolean = false;
}

 public Chapters: any;

this.http.get<Chapter>(this.baseUrl + 'api/Chapters').subscribe((response) => { this.Chapters = response; console.log(this.Chapters); }, error => console.log(error));
```

I am not getting the extra field 'Edit'.

Comment: the typings for this response basically disappear once the application is transpiled.  They are just for you, the developer to make your life easier during development, they will not automagically modify a response to have extra fields.  You need to instantiate and set those fields manually.  You can set a constructor on your class and use that to populate the extra fields, but otherwise it will not work as you intend.

Comment: i tried by changing my class as below.  export class Chapter {
  chapterId: number;
  chapterName: string;
  Edit: boolean;

  constructor(chapterId: number, chapterName: string) {
    this.chapterId = chapterId;
    this.chapterName = chapterName;
    this.Edit = false;
  }                But it didn't work. Am i doing correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like API `api/Chapters` returns array of objects which has `chapterid` and `chaptername`. If this is true then update your code like this:

```
this.http.get<Chapter[]>(this.baseUrl + 'api/Chapters')
                 .pipe(
                     map(chapters => {
                         return chapters.map(c => {return {...c, Edit: false}});
                     }),                     
                 )
                 .subscribe((response) => { this.Chapters = response; console.log(this.Chapters); }, error => console.log(error));
```

Comment: It worked. One return is missing in your solution. **this.http.get<Chapter[]>(this.baseUrl + 'api/Chapters').pipe(map(chapters => { return chapters.map(c => { return { ...c, Edit: false } } )  })).subscribe(val => console.log(val));**